# Atom Editor: Use Current file as an argument to any program

Tags: atom-editor

I'm new to Atom and I'm used to text editors that let you define external tools (like Visual Studio or UltraEdit) that let you pass arguments like the current file to any exe.

How do I achieve this in atom, for example I'd like to open the current file I'm editing in notepad.

Comment: This is for a custom package?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this: https://atom.io/packages/dqs-shell-commands
It allows you to run external commands.